# Create Density Heatmap Chart using Jquery with array of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, data-visualization

I got stuck while creating the density heatmap chart using highcharts.js.

I am able to create a heatmap chart but the heatmap chart does not fit to the entire width. I am expecting the my heatmap chart to look like the below screenshot. Any help will be much appreciated. Also, please suggest any other plugins to meet the expected behavior.
Thanks in Advance.
[[image: Expected Heatmap chart]]

HTML

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; max-width: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JS

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'contour',
        inverted: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura','Timd', 'Laudra'],

    },
    yAxis: {
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        title: null
    },
   colorAxis: {
        stops: [
             [0, '#5974FF'],
            [0.5, '#7FFF59'],
            [0.9, '#FFAF59']
        ]

    },
    series: [{
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91],[10, 0, 47], [10, 1, 114], [10, 2, 31], [10, 3, 48], [10, 4, 91]],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: 'Temperature<br/>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value} ℃</b>'
        }
    }]

});
```

The code is in JSFiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nsj5uzdw/22/).

Comment: Remove `max-width: 400px;`...?

Comment: This looks like an issue with the contour plugin you are using. Even their basic demo has the same issue (http://jsfiddle.net/nsj5uzdw/) when you change chart type from 'contour' to 'heatmap'. You could limit this by changing your start/end tick positions.

Comment: Many thianks for the update Halvor. But no luck. I have tried it already.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply WergeId. I will try your suggestions.. Also, Please suggest some other plugins to meet the exact requirement.. Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experiences with Highcharts, you have to **explicitly** define a width for your container `div`, whether that's a percentage or a fixed pixel width. `max-width` seems to be treated as an option (often overlooked) vs. a command. I hope this is helpful for you.